# Faster counts with mysql by sampling table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way I can get a count for records meeting a condition but my problem is the table is billions of records long and a basic count(*) is not possible as it times out.

I thought that maybe it would be possible to sample the table by doing something like selecting 1/4th of the records. I believe that older records will be more likely to match so I'd need a method which accounts for this (perhaps random sorting).

Is it possible or reasonable to query a certain percent of rows in mysql? And is this the smartest way to go about solving this problem?

The query I currently have which doesn't work is pretty simple:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE deleted_at IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue

Comment: Something to think about: typically when you hit a situation of billions of rows in MySQL, short of being a massive service, it's a sign that you might be storing data that may not belong in the database. Think of it like storing the individual pixels of an image, instead of just a reference to the image on a filesystem.

Comment: @Rogue I'd normally agree. Unfortunately these are already just references to file names stored on S3 and their size/filetype. We just have billions of files..

Comment: @Qwertie what type of files? What purpose do they serve?

Comment: User uploaded images. I'm trying to get a rough estimate on how many are soft deleted to work out if effort should be put in to cleaning them up but unfortunately I have not been able to run any queries which require a full table search.

Comment: At this point then it may come down to ensuring you have proper indexes, buffer sizing on InnoDB, and checking the execution with `EXPLAIN`. A desperate move may be to download the database table, and to use a temporary service (e.g. AWS) to host the data on some beefier hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` will 'instantly' give an approximate Row count.  (There is an equivalent `SELECT ... FROM information_schema.tables`.)  However, this may be significantly far off.

A count(*) on an index on any column in the `PRIMARY KEY` will be faster because it will be smaller.  But this still may not be fast enough.

There is no way to "sample".  Or at least no way that is reliably better than `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.  `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` with some simple query will do an estimate; again, not necessarily any better.

Please describe what kind of data you have; there may be some other tricks we can use.

See also [*Random*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) .  There may be a technique that will help you "sample".  Be aware that all techniques are subject to various factors of how the data was generated and whether there has been "churn" on the table.

Can you periodically run the full `COUNT(*)` and save it somewhere?  And then maintain the count after that?

I assume you don't have this case.  (Else the solution is trivial.)

- AUTO_INCREMENT id
- Never DELETEd or REPLACEd or INSERT IGNOREd or ROLLBACKd any rows

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I did eventually get an answer with a long running query and since this was a one off, a more performant trick won't be needed. But I think you have answered the topic of the question with it not being possible to use some kind of sampling method.

Answer (score 0):

ADD an index key with `deleted_at` column, to improve time execution
and try to count `id` if id is set.

Comment: I'd like to avoid modifying the table if possible. Building the index would take quite a long time and this is a once off query to get an estimate on the number of deleted records.